# Select SUM from subquery while using whereHas in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery, laravel-5.4

I have 2 tables, `customers` and `customer_invoices`, and I want to get all the customers with a condition on their invoices, and select specific columns (customers.id, customers.last_name, and the sum of the `total_price` of the invoices for each customer), I have this query :

```
$result = Customer::whereHas('customerInvoices', function(Builder $q) {
            $q->where('customer_invoices.status', 1);
        })->select([
            'customers.id',
            'customers.last_name',
            \DB::raw('SUM(customer_invoices.total_price) as sum')
        ])->get();
```

`customerInvoices` is the relation :

```
public function customerInvoices() {

    return $this->hasMany(CustomerInvoice::class);
}
```

I want to use subqueries instead of joins, so here I can't select this `\DB::raw('SUM(customer_invoices.total_price) as sum')`, or else I get this error of course :

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_invoices.total_price' in 'field list' (SQL: select `customers`.`id`, `customers`.`last_name`, SUM(customer_invoices.total_price) as sum from `customers` where exists (select * from `customer_invoices` where `customers`.`id` = `customer_invoices`.`customer_id` and `customer_invoices`.`status` = 1))"
```

How can I achieve this without using joins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to get sum from related model as

```
$result = Customer::select([
            'customers.id',
            'customers.last_name'
        ])->withCount([
            'customerInvoices as invoice_sum' => function($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(total_price)'));
            }
        ])->whereHas('customerInvoices', function(Builder $q) {
            $q->where('customer_invoices.status', 1);
        })->get();
```

Another approach to get sum, you can define a `hasOne()` relation in your Customer model like

```
public function invoice_sum()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CustomerInvoice::class)
        ->select('customer_id',
            DB::raw('sum(total_price)')
        )->groupBy('customer_id');
}
```

And in query builder

```
$result = Customer::select([
            'customers.id',
            'customers.last_name',
        ])->with('invoice_sum')
          ->whereHas('customerInvoices', function(Builder $q) {
            $q->where('customer_invoices.status', 1);
        })->get();
```

As per [Eloquent : withCount() overrides the $columns on get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15576) issue first put `select()` mehtod and then use `with()` function

Comment: I only get the `id` and `last_name` in the result with this.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I get `"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoice_sum' in 'field list' (SQL: select `customers`.`id`, `customers`.`last_name`, `invoice_sum` from `customers` where exists (select * from `customer_invoices` where `customers`.`id` = `customer_invoices`.`customer_id` and `customer_invoices`.`status` = 1))"`

Comment: @dwix ignore my previous comment and see updated answer