# eloquent sum of relation's column in single query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

in this query i have three table such as `radio`, `radio_channels` and `radio_channels_files` which into that i want to calculate one column which that is into `radio_channels_files` table as new column such as `duration_sum`, my below code work but i can't calculate this column

```
class Radio extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'logo_path' => 'array',
        'cover_path' => 'array'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RadioCategory::class);
    }

    public function channels()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RadioChannels::class);
    }
}
    

class RadioChannelsFiles extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'image' => 'array',
        //'keywords' => 'array',
    ];

    public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RadioChannels::class,'playlist_id');
    }
}

   

class RadioChannels extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'image' => 'array'
    ];

    public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Radio::class);
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RadioChannelsFiles::class , 'playlist_id');
    }

    public function duration_sum()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(RadioChannelsFiles::class ,'playlist_id')
            ->select('duration',
                DB::raw('sum(duration)')
            )->groupBy('duration');
    }
}


$channels = Radio::with(['category', 'channels' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['files','duration_sum']);
}])->paginate(50);
```

i get `null` output:

```
#relations: array:2 [▼
     "files" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1422 ▶}
     "duration_sum" => null //should return sum of duration from files
     ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944636/select-sum-from-subquery-while-using-wherehas-in-laravel#answer-52944764

Comment: @frogeyedman i think yes, it does, i'm trying to use this solution

Comment: @frogeyedman i can't, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

i figured out how can i get it

```
public function getRadiosList(Request $request)
{
    $radios = Radio::with(['category', 'playLists' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['files','duration_sum']);
    }])->get();

    return response()->json(['data' => $radios, 'statusCode' => 1], 200);
}
```

model:

```
public function duration_sum()
{
    return $this->hasOne(RadioPlaylistsFiles::class, 'playlist_id')
        ->select('playlist_id',
            DB::raw('sum(duration) as `all_duration`')
        )->groupBy('playlist_id');
}
```